# Sending Application login credentials to AppStore reviewers

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I've just uploaded my application to the appstore. The application requires a username / password to log-in, but I was never prompted for any credentials during the upload process. Does anyone know how I can send the reviewers my credentials without having to wait for them to review and request the credentials?

Comment: How do people register to use the app?

If you can't register through/from the app then it's likely to get rejected because of that. They won't allow an app which people can't use.

Comment: Actually, I believe its acceptable by Apple that an app requires the use of an account created outside the app. You just need to provide a test account for the reviewer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the app, there is a field near the bottom of one of the screens for "review notes" which is where login information should be placed. You may be able to in to iTunes connect and edit this field. I have no apps waiting for review at the moment, so I am unsure if this field is editable, but it should be.

Answer (score 5):

The bottom-most field on the page where you edit your app's metadata (title, description, keywords, etc.) is titled "Review Notes (optional)". It is exactly for your purpose. I don't know if you can still edit it after you have submitted the app for review.

Answer (score 1):

App demo account details can be updated under "App Review Information" in iTunes connect as shown below image. Even the details can be provided under "Notes" in iTunes app information

[image]