# Send test login credentials to Apple Review Team

Tags: iphone, authentication, appstore-approval, facebook-login

I am ready to submit my iphone application to Apple Store. In my application , I have my own login functionality (same like website) which is used to access the application. Also I have "Login with Facebook" functionality.

Do I need to send the test login credentials for my own login functionality as well as Facebook login to the Apple Review Team in "Review Notes in metadata" ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you not searched the same before posting the question?

Comment: Duplicate of -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275140/sending-application-login-credentials-to-appstore-reviewers

Comment: @RIP , I searched before posting. But my question is "Do I need to provide FACEBOOK credentials also?"

Comment: i don't think you need to provide them facebook login credentials.

Comment: That's it RIP. I don't think for this you need to vote down. Any way thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide them with any login credentials, and you can just return some dummy data from the server, so that the App review team can review the functionality of the entire app.

Comment: Do I need to provide FACEBOOK credentials also?

Comment: If the functionality of the app does not change for the user, if using facebook login method instead of the conventional way, I don't think you would need to send them a facebook user profile too.